# Bridge between Tron and ETH networks

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, usdt

I am trying to implement the wallet with USDT as asset, which supports both ETH and Tron networks. I wanted also to add function to convert your USDT from ETH to Tron network or vice versa inside of my app.

So far I found cool library web3py on python, which does most of the job of generating wallets, sending/receiving assets and etc. I was wondering where can I get info about developing the bridge between ETH and Tron? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on your needs.

The most straightforward bridge is something like this:

1. A contract on both sides which receive assets and mint/release assets
2. A backend system which monitors when the said contracts receive assets, and calls the contract at the other side to release assets accordingly

This approach is very centralized and has a clear single point of failure. But to get anymore more decentralized is not easy. I would therefore suggest to start with a similar centralized version and then you can slowly make it more decentralized if needed/wanted.

Making a decentralized bridge would probably involve lots of validators and incentives for them to stay honest.